'Camera' object has no attribute 'light_source'
I was looking up the manim code for videos created by 3b1b and in the hologram video the double slit part caught my attention so i installed manim(CE) and have been experimenting with it a little bit then i tried the code i tried my best importing the code to the community version till there were no errors but when i ran it in sideview i got the error "AttributeError: 'Camera' object has no attribute 'light_source' " and have been looking up for any solutions but i can't find any please help me with this and if anyone needs more references just ask as i don't know what all could be relevant.
def setup(self):
    super().setup()
    self.camera.light_source.move_to(self.light_position)

error traceback img
